# Fancybox iFrame Overlay not displaying

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox-2

I use the below code to display a pop-up on certain product pages to confirm the user is over 18, this function works great however the overlay that fades out the background page is not displayed.
Looking at the code after the page has rendered I can see that the div "fancybox-overlay" is not present when my iFrame displays.
I have tried using the helpers as displayed in the code below but with no luck!

edit: I have also been trying to remove the close button from the top right using "closeBtn: false" in the helper but this doesn't work either!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/newsletter/newsletter.js"></script>
<script>
veriage = getCookie('ageveri');
if (!veriage){veriage = 10};
if (veriage == 10){veriage = 20;

  jQuery.fancybox({

        href: "/js/agecheck/age-check.html",
        type: 'iframe',
        'width': 450,
        helpers:  {
                  overlay : true
        } 

            });

}
if (veriage != 10){
cookieData = veriage;
setCookie('ageveri',cookieData,expDate)
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have seen the issue when firing fancybox before the DOM is ready. Try to wrap your code inside the `ready()` method. http://jsfiddle.net/4md3g/

Comment: Thanks, wrapping the whole code inside the ready() method worked a treat.